# Разделить вектор на список векторов

Tags: r

У меня есть вектор следующего вида:

```
foo <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1)
```

Я хочу получить из него следующий список векторов:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
(5, 4)
(1)
```

Т.е выделить группы точек, значения в которых больше какого-либо порога (в данном случае 0). Сейчас сделал такой костыльный алгоритм:

```
thres <- 0 # порог

foo <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1)
bar <- list()
temp <- c()

for(i in 1:length(foo))
{
  if(foo[i] > thres)
  {
    temp <- append(temp, foo[i])
  }
  else
  {
    if(length(temp) > 0)
    {
      bar[length(bar)+1] <- list(temp)
      temp <- c()     
    }
  }
}
```

Проблема в том, что, если вектор не заканчивается нулём, то последняя группа точек не попадает в список. Получается, нужно ещё вводить дополнительный флаг. Может быть есть какие-то более простые решения с использованием встроенных функций или каких-нибудь дополнительных библиотек?

Comment: В принципе, можно всегда дописывать в конец вектора ноль, это никак не повлияет на результат, но алгоритм станет работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем логический вектор, кумулятивную сумму и `split`.

```
x <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1)
value <- 0
idx <- x == value
split(x[!idx], cumsum(idx)[!idx])
#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 4 5 6 7
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] 5 4
#> 
#> $`8`
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: Обновил ответ. Теперь используются только функции из `base`.

Answer (score 0):

Придумал вот такой (тоже костыльный) вариант:

```
foo <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1)
foo <- paste(foo, collapse = "")
strsplit(foo, "0")[[1]]
```

Получается

```
[1] ""     "123"  ""     "4567" ""     ""     "54"   ""     "1"
```

Дальше остается только выбрать строки длиной больше 0 и разделить обратно на числа. Если числе больше чем из одной цифры, придется указывать что-то типа `collapse = "_"` и разделять по `"_"`.